# Should it be necessary to call ActiveRecord::Base.reload after updating a nested attribute collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reload, nested-attributes

I am finding (noodling around in script/console) that if I add a new item to the associated collection, I don't have to call foo.reload to see the resulting change:

```
foo.bars
=> []
foo.bars_attributes = [{ :person_id => '288', :task_id => '1237' }]
=> [{ :person_id=>"288", :task_id=>"1237" }]
foo.save
=> true
foo.bars
=> [#<Bar id: 6, person_id: 288, task_id => 1237>]
```

Terrific. But when I remove an item from the collection, I do have to call foo.reload before the change (visible in DB after call to save) is reflected in my collection:

```
foo.bars_attributes = [{ :id => '6', :_delete => '1' }]
= [{ :_delete=>"1", :id=>"6" }]
foo.save
=> true
foo.bars
=> [#<Bar id: 6, person_id: 288, task_id => 1237>]
foo.reload
foo.bars
=> []
```

Is this normal, or am I doing something slightly wrong in the association update?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing in rails 3.0 (no yet released at the time of your writing).  It was reaping havoc with a validation that required a minimum number of associations.  The parent instance would say it was valid, even after the update had removed all the child attributes.

I devised a workaround by including a module in my `Parent` model with the following method, and substituting that for `update_attributes()` in the controller's `update` method:

```
  def update_with_association_size_validations(attributes)
    update_successful = false
    self.class.transaction do
      self.update_attributes(attributes)
      self.reload
      update_successful = true if self.valid?
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless update_successful
    end
    update_successful
  end
```

This is by no means a perfect solution, and it's untested on more deeply nested associations.

Better let than never, almost a year to the day!